# Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, flask

So, I am trying to add the images name that I save in the specified directory, and its getting added to the database However this error keeps coming up. Although the images keep getting saved in the specified directory. Here are all my files Models.py

```
class Tickets(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
  ticket_text = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
  date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=datetime.utcnow)
  status = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
  priority = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
  created_by_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
  expert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'),nullable=False)
  project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'),nullable=False)
  comment = db.relationship('Comment', backref='title', lazy='dynamic')
  attach = db.relationship('Attachment', backref='ticket', lazy='dynamic')

class Attachment(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  file = db.Column(db.String(140))
  ticket_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tickets.id'), nullable=False)
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/ticket/<ticket_id>',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def ticket(ticket_id):
    ticket = Tickets.query.get_or_404(ticket_id)
    com = Comment.query.filter_by(ticket_id=ticket.id).first()
    form = CommentForm()
    attachform = AttachForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit() and form.body.data:
        comment = Comment(body=form.body.data,ticket_id=ticket_id,author = current_user.username)
        db.session.add(comment)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your comment has been published.')
        return redirect(url_for('ticket', ticket_id=ticket_id))
    if attachform.validate_on_submit():
        if attachform.file.data:
            picture_file = save_file(attachform.file.data)
            attachment = Attachment(file=picture_file,ticket_id=ticket_id)
            db.session.add(attachment)
            ticket.attach = picture_file
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your file has been published.')
        return redirect(url_for('ticket', ticket_id=ticket_id))
    file = url_for('static', filename='files/' + str(ticket.attach))
    return render_template('ticket.html', title=ticket.title,file=file ,ticket=ticket,form=form,comment=com,attachform=attachform)
```

error is on this line

```
ticket.attach = picture_file
```

Comment: This code does not refer to `_sa_instance_state`, so the error must be somewhere else in code that you haven't shown us.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: sorry, I updated, please take a look

Comment: `ticket.attach = attachment`?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `ticket_id` as a string, when it should be an integer (key):

Try:

```
@app.route('/ticket/<int:ticket_id>',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def ticket(ticket_id):
    # or use ticket_id = int(ticket_id)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should query `Tickets` with `Attachment` using outer join.

```
ticket = db.session.query(Tickets, Attachment).outerjoin(Attachment, Tickets.id == Attachment.tickets_id).get_or_404(ticket_id)
```

after this query, you need to access table like this.

```
ticket.Tickets.xxx
ticket.Attachments.xxx
```

So, you set attachment file to `ticket.Attachments`.

```
ticket.Attachments.tickets_id == tickets_id
ticket.Attachments.file = picture_file
```

if `ticket.Attachments` is None,

```
tichet.Attachment = attachment
```